# Set an Environment Variable in Apache and System

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, environment-variables, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'd like to set an environment variable in both system and httpd.

I set the variable, let's say `IMPORTANT_FOLDER = /MY/PATH`, in `/etc/profile` and it works for all system users.

What i want to do is to bring this variable into `httpd`, so that it can be used by some php code.
I managed to make the var available only by adding `SetEnv IMPORTANT_FOLDER = /MY/PATH` in my httpd configurations.

Could you kindly provide me a method to pass the system variable into apache? The important thing for me is to make it centralized.

I'm using apache 2.4 on redhat 7.